# Having trouble converting dataframe string to float

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert a column of strings to float after reading from a csv into pandas dataframe. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: size
```

The code I am using is the following:

```
df['size'] = df['size'].apply(lambda x:float(x))
```

Any ideas?

A sample of my dataframe is below:

```
>>> df.head(4)

                         localtime  symbol exchange   price  size
NaN                      localtime  symbol     exch   price  size
 0   2017-08-01 13:30:00.130514241    AAPL     NSDQ  149.08    71
 1   2017-08-01 13:30:00.148672863    AAPL     NSDQ  149.05    33
 2   2017-08-01 13:30:00.148695312    AAPL       BX  149.05    45
```

Comment: Can you look into values for `size` series. Looks like it has string `size`

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe?

Comment: they are all numeric values within the csv

Comment: tks chrisz, just did

Comment: It doesn't look like your csv was read correctly. It looks like the columns names were also read into the first row of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pd.to_numeric`

```
df['size'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['size'], errors='coerce')
```

or:

```
df['size'] = df['size'].astype(float)
```

From the data you have posted looks like you have “size” in your column. That is why you are getting the error. You can use `skiprows` to skip any unwanted row.